# Android Custom ListView EditText Focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am having custom listview that contains EditText and Spinner, the problem I am facing, when I type in the EditText and move to Spinner after choosing a value in the spinner, the focus goes back to the EditText. I have 2 EditText and 8 Spinners in the ListView, every time when I choose something in the spinner the focus goes to the EditText, have to scroll back to Spinner. I had removed RequestFocus in the EditText but still it is giving problem. Can anyone help me to solve this issue

I had given listview like this

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            >
</ListView>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/LocText"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/FirstText"
    >

</EditText>


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spDev"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/device"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"

    android:textColor="@color/hookup_positive"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LocText"

    />
```

Comment: Your xml code has some mistakes like empty listView. Please fix it

Comment: I gave it as example because the XML code is very big so instead of posting the complete code I just gave what is needed. EditText and Spinner are in separate XML file, ListView in the separate XML file

Comment: Better  it would be a gist with whole content, but ok.